# Is a 500 GB PS3 enough to run Grand Theft Auto 5 on ultra graphics settings?

Tags: ps3

I will be buying a PlayStation 3. And I want to know if 500 GB is enough to run Grand Theft Auto 5 on Ultra Graphic Settings? I also want to know if 500 GB is a lot for the PS3 and what is the biggest amount of GB you can get in a PS3?

Comment: Hard drive size has nothing to do with graphical fidelity.  GTA 5 runs the same on all PS3s, regardless of their model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fear you lack a little knowledge on what you are intending on buying.
Unlike PC versions of games ps3 and xbox 360 have one graphic setting (compared PC versions about a medium to high setting). 
To answer your other question 500gb is the highest ps3 size you can buy in stock form. However you can upgrade the hard drive to have more space...

***Sub-Note***: Please do some research before buying. Finding the information to this took a google search. I can put sources if needed but I feel that I needn't.